# VBA Removing Extra Rows After Certain # Has Been Reached

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA question and looking for the most effective way to do this.

I have a table and in Column L is a list of facilities for sales. I am trying to delete all duplicates of the same facility after the first 5. Some facilities have 2 rows, some have 20 so my original thought and experience in VBA of looping through runs into a roadblock.

This sheet is also > 100,000 rows so would take a long, long time.

The sheet would look something like this in column L:

[image]

Appreciate all help in advance, looking forward to learning something new here!

Comment: What specific problem did you have with your attempt?

Comment: Ca you please show us the code you have so far and let us know exactly what the problem you are facing is

Comment: Put a countifs formula in column b, paste as values, and then delete anything over 5. You could make a macro do it, but its probably easier to just put in a filter and delete anything over t

Comment: My code would have been a while loop storing the first value as a temp and going down the list until 5 was reached, than deleting those after it. Where I was running into a mental hurdle was how to work it if there was 2 or 3 instead of a 5 of a facility but I suppose I could have used a break out of the loop and stored the current cell I was in as a temporary location to move onto the next facility. Thanks for the tips guys. I will make my next question with my thoughts more clear on my own attempt at a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove Too Many Duplicates

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub RemoveTooManyDupes()
        
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 12
    Const MAX_DUPES_COUNT As Long = 2
    Const DELETE_CRITERION As String = "Nope"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count + 1 ' extend by one column
    
    Dim erg As Range: Set erg = rg.Resize(, cCount) ' extended range
    Dim ecrg As Range: Set ecrg = erg.Columns(cCount) ' extended (last) column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ecrg.Value = ws.Evaluate("Row(1:" & rg.Rows.Count & ")") ' integer sequence
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN) ' criteria column
    
    Dim Data(): Data = crg.Value ' criteria data
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long, rString As String
    
    For r = 2 To rCount
        rString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        dict(rString) = dict(rString) + 1
        If dict(rString) > MAX_DUPES_COUNT Then Data(r, 1) = DELETE_CRITERION
    Next r
    
    crg.Value = Data
    erg.Sort crg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    
    Dim edrg As Range: Set edrg = erg.Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1) ' no headers
    
    erg.AutoFilter CRITERIA_COLUMN, DELETE_CRITERION ' note 'erg'
    
    Dim vrg As Range ' visible range (filtered rows)
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = edrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' note 'edrg'
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
    erg.Sort ecrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    ecrg.ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Too many dupes removed.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great and I learned quite a bit from it. Much appreciated.